# How do I change the config.yml in sentry docker?

Tags: docker, configuration-files, sentry

I have setup sentry with docker in a machine. I would like to integrate GitHub plugin. For this I need to add some settings to the config file.

The docker compose file is, ,

```
version: '2'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis

  postgres:
    image: 'postgres'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DBNAME: sentry
      POSTGRES_DBUSER: sentry
      POSTGRES_DBPASS: sentry
    volumes:
     - ~/sentry/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  sentry:
    image: sentry
    depends_on:
     - redis
     - postgres
    links:
     - redis
     - postgres
    ports:
     - 9000:9000
    environment:
      SENTRY_SECRET_KEY: '<SECRET-KEY>'
      SENTRY_POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
      SENTRY_DB_USER: postgres
      SENTRY_DB_PASSWORD: postgres
      SENTRY_REDIS_HOST: redis
      SENTRY_SERVER_EMAIL: '<FROM-EMAIL>'
      SENTRY_EMAIL_HOST: <EMAIL-HOST>
      SENTRY_EMAIL_PORT: <EMAIL-PORT>
      SENTRY_EMAIL_USER: '<USER-NAME>'
      SENTRY_EMAIL_PASSWORD: '<USER-PASSWD>'
      SENTRY_EMAIL_USE_TLS: 'true'

  sentry-cron:
    image: sentry
    depends_on:
     - redis
     - postgres
    command: "sentry run cron"
    environment:
      SENTRY_SECRET_KEY: '<SECRET-KEY>'
      SENTRY_POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
      SENTRY_DB_USER: postgres
      SENTRY_DB_PASSWORD: postgres
      SENTRY_REDIS_HOST: redis
      SENTRY_SERVER_EMAIL: '<FROM-EMAIL>'      
      SENTRY_EMAIL_HOST: <EMAIL-HOST>
      SENTRY_EMAIL_PORT: <EMAIL-PORT>
      SENTRY_EMAIL_USER: '<USER-NAME>'
      SENTRY_EMAIL_PASSWORD: '<USER-PASSWD>'
      SENTRY_EMAIL_USE_TLS: 'true'

  sentry-worker-1:
    image: sentry
    depends_on:
     - redis
     - postgres
    command: "sentry run worker"
    environment:
      SENTRY_SECRET_KEY: '<SECRET-KEY>'
      SENTRY_POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
      SENTRY_DB_USER: postgres
      SENTRY_DB_PASSWORD: postgres
      SENTRY_REDIS_HOST: redis
      SENTRY_SERVER_EMAIL: '<FROM-EMAIL>'      
      SENTRY_EMAIL_HOST: <EMAIL-HOST>
      SENTRY_EMAIL_PORT: <EMAIL-PORT>
      SENTRY_EMAIL_USER: '<USER-NAME>'
      SENTRY_EMAIL_PASSWORD: '<USER-PASSWD>'
      SENTRY_EMAIL_USE_TLS: 'true'
```

The containers running are,

```
root@sentry:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES                                                                                         
af70794fbd0d        sentry              "/entrypoint.sh run …"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   root_sentry_1                                                                                 
733862200ac9        sentry              "/entrypoint.sh sent…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   9000/tcp                 root_sentry-cron_1                                                                            
4d6bc8691010        sentry              "/entrypoint.sh sent…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   9000/tcp                 root_sentry-worker-1_1
1cd4f132ccca        redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   6379/tcp                 root_redis_1
0c887f4b5ee0        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   5432/tcp                 root_postgres_1
```

I found a config file in `/etc/sentry` in `sentry_1` container. Is the config file or am I missing up something?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/sentry/) they suggest to use custom image using .

`sentry:onbuild`

> This image makes it easy to custom build your own Sentry instance by
>   copying in a custom `config.yml` and/or `sentry.conf.py` file and
>   installing plugins from `requirements.txt`.
>
> It's also possible to develop custom extensions within your onbuild
>   package. If the build directory contains a `setup.py` file, this will
>   also get installed.

[See the official Sentry documentation for more information.](https://docs.getsentry.com/on-premise/server/installation/)

> To create your custom `sentry:onbuild`  package, simply do the following:
>
> Create a Dockerfile containing `FROM sentry:onbuild` In the same
>   directory, add your custom `configuration files`. You can get copies
>   of those files to use as templates from the docker-sentry GitHub repo.
>   Build your image: `docker build -t mysentry .`
>   **Run your custom image using mysentry instead of sentry.**